# nsIAlertsService from Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have one question regarding firefox and nsIAlertsService from extension. It is possible to force the alert to close on browser close?( because if I close the browser, the alert remains, but it is useless, it's not working).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Alerts_and_Notifications

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the answer is "no" - the API doesn't allow to force-close the alert, and normally it isn't necessary because the alert is closed anyway at most 3 seconds later. You could hack this by going to the `alert:alert` window via window mediator directly and closing it, this won't work on Mac and Android however (different notification approach there).

Comment: Can you be more specific about the code for alert:alert?Thanks

Comment: @WladimirPalant can you please give more detail on how to hack this. i am very interested because i spent a long time once trying to hack it on windows so that the notification doesnt disappear automatically after 3seconds, but after like 30 seconds, and i also tried to give it a close button and stuff. in the end i just ended up making my own panel

Comment: @Noit: Making your own panel is the better solution anyway.

Comment: ah yah that way it works on all os'es huh? ok got it thanks @WladimirPalant but im interested in this hack method because i have been trying to hack the login nsILoginManager for long time, im trying to access functions like _getPasswordOrigin and _getFormFields so i can fix the form fill, as it doesnt fill out many forms. I have been asking for ages on goolge groups and no one answers :( 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.extensions/W6Wn937IAjg
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.extensions/OCpqyoOnHV0

Comment: hi wlad here is my other nsiloginmanager topic on google groups no one replied too :( ive been trying to hack that thing for ages
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mozilla.dev.extensions/L6LWZas2ocE #